# NTP Time Wrong on ntp.org?

Tags: windows, time, ntp

My Windows Server 2012r2 server (vm inside of esxi) is going crazy and thinking that it is Dec. 2, 2033. The oddest part about this is that it is saying that is what NTP is telling it.

```
20:25:23, -335476751.7423648s
PS C:\Users\administrator.CF> w32tm /stripchart /computer:pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:3
Tracking pool.ntp.org [96.126.122.39:123].
Collecting 3 samples.
The current time is 12/2/2033 8:25:29 PM.
20:25:29, -335476751.7507491s
20:25:31, -335476751.7493971s
20:25:33, -335476751.7495433s
PS C:\Users\administrator.CF> w32tm /stripchart /computer:0.ro.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:3
Tracking 0.ro.pool.ntp.org [162.159.200.123:123].
Collecting 3 samples.
The current time is 12/2/2033 8:25:42 PM.
20:25:42, -335476751.7499849s
20:25:44, -335476751.7544872s
20:25:46, -335476751.7553163s
PS C:\Users\administrator.CF> w32tm /stripchart /computer:1.ro.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:3
Tracking 1.ro.pool.ntp.org [185.173.16.132:123].
Collecting 3 samples.
The current time is 12/2/2033 8:25:52 PM.
20:25:52, -335476751.7387477s
20:25:54, -335476751.7432034s
20:25:56, -335476751.7432303s
PS C:\Users\administrator.CF> w32tm /stripchart /computer:2.ro.pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:3
Tracking 2.ro.pool.ntp.org [93.190.144.3:123].
Collecting 3 samples.
The current time is 12/2/2033 8:26:02 PM.
20:26:02, -335476751.7415654s
20:26:04, -335476751.7517593s
20:26:06, -335476751.7508327s
PS C:\Users\administrator.CF>
```

Anyone have any idea how or why this is happening? How to resolve this that the right time is set on the server?

==== EDIT ====

For @jaromanda X, w32tm shows:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.CF> w32tm /tz
Time zone: Current:TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD Bias: 360min (UTC=LocalTime+Bias)
  [Standard Name:"Central Standard Time" Bias:0min Date:(M:11 D:1 DoW:0)]
  [Daylight Name:"Central Daylight Time" Bias:-60min Date:(M:3 D:2 DoW:0)]
```

Comment: none of those ntp servers have the wrong time, the issue is something in your computer - what is the output of `w32tm /tz`

Comment: Do you know for sure that "The current time" is indicating NTP time and not local system time? It sounds to me like it is showing the latter, obtained from the hypervisor and not via NTP.

Comment: @user1686, you are correct, that's the local time as calculated by Windows. If I run the same command I get:
`> w32tm /stripchart /computer:pool.ntp.org /dataonly /samples:3
Tracking pool.ntp.org [45.159.204.28:123].
Collecting 3 samples.
The current time is 17/04/2023 10:55:40.
10:55:40, +00.0170085s
10:55:42, +00.0222229s
10:55:44, +00.0185853s`
I'm in UTC+1 and the current local time is 10:55.

Comment: Right, then that sounds like actual NTP time is correct, and the server is adjusting its clock from somewhere else. Do system logs have any mention of VMware ESXi hypervisor clock or something along those lines?

Comment: @user1686 - the hypervisor has the right time though. ESXi shows: "Date/time on host Tuesday, April 18, 2023, 16:53:22 UTC Install date Saturday, January 06, 2018, 06:50:35 UTC"

Comment: NTP wasn't updating the time because the time drift was too far. From eventvwr: "The time service has detected that the system time needs to be  changed by -335476750 seconds. The time service will not change the system time by more than 172800 seconds. Verify that your time and time zone are correct, and that the time source pool.ntp.org (ntp.m|0x0|0.0.0.0:123->45.33.53.84:123) is working properly." Manually fixing the time and then resetting/restarting w32 fixed everything. How the time got so off in the first place, I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is with the time service, you can reset the service to
a default state by running the following inside an elevated
Command Prompt (CMD):

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
```

You may verify your time server this way :

- Run `timedate.cpl`
- Position to the "Internet Time" tab
- Click "Change settings…" and verify your time server
  (mine is `time.windows.com`)
- Ensure that "Synchronize with an Internet time server" is checked
- Click on "Update Now" and click OK to save the changes.